# SQS Receiver - Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-messaging

I was trying to create a SQS queue listener in my spring boot app using the code below

```
AmazonSQSAsyncClient amazonSQSAsyncClient= new AmazonSQSAsyncClient(getProfileCredentialsProvider());
```

However AmazonSQSAsyncClient seems to be deprecated. Is there a different way of using builder to create this object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
AmazonSQSAsyncClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(getProfileCredentialsProvider())
                .build();
```

That is really mentioned in the JavaDocs:

```
* @deprecated use {@link AmazonSQSAsyncClientBuilder#withCredentials(AWSCredentialsProvider)}
 */
@Deprecated
public AmazonSQSAsyncClient(AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider) {
```

Comment: Thanks @Artem Bilan. I was checking the decompiled class and it seemed to be missing. This helps

Answer (score 1):

For those of you looking for standard way of defining listeners.

Include ***spring-cloud-aws-messaging*** in your application, beware to not include the ***spring-cloud-aws-started-messaging***.

Then you gain access to two ways of creating listeners:

```
@SqsListener(value = "logical queue name")
```

and programatically

```
@Autowired
private SimpleMessageListenerContainer simpleMessageListenerContainer;
...
simpleMessageListenerContainer.start("logical queue name");
```

spring will handle the creating of AmazonSQS client for you.

NOTE: for the `@SqsListener` annotation you need `@EnableSqs`